# Reference request: Carnot Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a group and let $\Gamma_G(k)$ be the $k$th term of the lower central series of $G$. For each $k\geq 1$, set $\mathcal{L}_G(k)=\Gamma_G(k)/\Gamma_G(k+1)$ and $$\mathcal{L}_G:=\bigoplus_{k\geq 1}\mathcal{L}_G(k).$$ Then $\mathcal{L}_G$ has a graded Lie algebra structure induced from the commutator bracket on $G$.

I [heard](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188191/does-the-associated-lie-algebra-determine-a-group) that $\mathcal{L}_G$ is called the *Carnot Algebra*. Could any one provide some reference of Carnot Algebras (definition, basic facts, etc.)? I never heard of this terminology; for all the papers that I have read, $\mathcal{L}_G$ is usually called the *associated Lie algebra*.

Comment: A Carnot (Lie) algebra is the Lie algebra of a certain simply connected nilpotent Lie group, namely of a [Carnot group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_group).

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde! The wiki article seems quite concise; any introduction references available?

Comment: There is a good introduction of Carnot groups and algebras in Yves Cornuliers artilce [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5295).

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde for the link!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Algebra is called the [Carnot group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_group).
[Google](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=carnot+algebra) and search for "Carnot Groups and Carnot solvmanifolds".

Comment: Many thanks for the reference!